# How to save state of previous fragment on back pressed of next fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

My `FragmentManager` code look likes so, what should I do so that the behaviour in question can be achieved?

```
               supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(HomeFragment.newInstance())
                    .apply {
                        replace(
                            R.id.fragment_container_view,
                            HomeFragment.newInstance()
                        )

                        setCustomAnimations(
                            android.R.anim.slide_out_right,
                            android.R.anim.fade_out,
                            android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
                            android.R.anim.fade_out
                        )

                        addToBackStack(FragmentType.HOME_FRAGMENT)
                        commit()
                    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverfflow!, Please post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)